# Let $A$ be a linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Prove that $A$ is bounded $\iff \exists h\in D~(A \text{ is continuous at }h)$

Tags: continuity, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I don't know how to prove this because the only thing I know if something is continuous then it's e.g. Cauchy continuous, but not on a single element $h$. It's like saying $f(x)$ is continuous on $x_0=2$, so what does this even mean?

The only thing I know from our lecture which could help us prove this potentially is

$$A\ \text{is bounded}\Leftrightarrow \:\exists \:_{M\ge 0}\:\forall _{h\in H}\: \|Ah\| \le M\|h\|$$

But as I said, I don't know how to start and what this even mean

Important note: $D\left(A\right)\subset H$ is the domain of operator $A.$

Comment: Do you know the definition of a function being continuous at a point $x_0$ in a metric space? This is what you need to use, using the metric induced by the Hilbert space inner product.

Comment: Can't we just use the Cauchy definition, but just that we are approaching $x_0$? If not, then no, I don't know the definition

Comment: I would use the preposition "at"; i.e., $A$ is continuous at $h$.

Comment: You are right, it should be at since we treat h as a point

Comment: *Ho to start*: Given that $A$ is continuous at some point $h$, show that it is continuous at $0$.  Use linearity to do this.

Comment: But what is the definition of continuity at some point in a metric space in the first place? I don't know if we had this in topology

Comment: $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \exists \delta \gt 0 ~ (d(x, h) \lt \delta \Rightarrow \vert Ax - Ah \vert \lt \varepsilon)$.